AWS Lambda and .NET Task.WhenAll
We've been investigating the possibility of moving some of our .NET apps into serverless via AWS Lambda.
As we understand it Lambda only supports single threaded applications. While we know you can't equate Tasks and threads many of our workloads use Task.WhenAll to achieve performance improvements, how would this work in a single threaded environment?

Your assumption is wrong https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70849800/does-aws-lamda-support-multi-threading

Voted to close however yes - you're fine using Task.WhenAll. Lambda is just like any regular environment other than the ephemeral nature.
